# SQL line and header breaks issues

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a table with 17 columns. Based on this table I need to generate a local CSV file from a remote database. I define some set statements to display column names only once, no sql banner, line count and some others.

```
 "my sql connection"<<EOF>> test_file.csv
 SET TAB OFF ECHO OFF FEEDBACK OFF LINESIZE 5000 SQLPROMPT '' TRIMSPOOL OFF HEADING OFF UNDERLINE OFF PAGESIZE 0
 select * from my_table where ROWNUM <= 50;
 exit
 EOF
```

Simple, right?

I'm facing issues relate to record lines and header breaks. Even with LINESIZE 5000 when I open my csv file they are all broken and my headers too

Comment: You won't get CSV output with `select *`, or even selecting the specific columns which is preferable anyway, in SQL\*Plus. (SQLcl and SQL Developer have options to do that though). You can change `colsep` but then you get a load of whitespace. What is the maximum length of a line - the total size of all the columns (with implicit number/data conversion)? Are you running and opening the file on the same OS - maybe you're seeing line break issues, depending on what you open it with? Do you have values with line breaks? Showing an example would help, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest following approach (to save some time using the 17 columns). I suppose You'd want ' as an delimiter.

So first You can generate the command itself (I'm using query to USER_TABLES but You can easily modify the query to suit Your needs)

```
set pagesize 0
set linesize 5000
set trimspool on
(select q'!"my sql connection"<<EOF>> test_file.csv
 SET TAB OFF ECHO OFF FEEDBACK OFF LINESIZE 5000 SQLPROMPT '' TRIMSPOOL OFF HEADING OFF UNDERLINE OFF PAGESIZE 0!' from dual)
 union all
(select 
  q'!select '!' ||
  listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by table_name) 
  || q'!' from dual union all!'
  header
from all_tab_cols where table_name =
-- MODIFY TO YOUR TABLE NAME HERE [1]:
'USER_TABLES'
)
union all
(select 
  'select ' ||
  listagg(column_name, q'! || ',' || !') within group (order by table_name) 
-- REPLACE USER_TABLES TO YOUR TABLE NAME HERE [2]:
|| ' from user_tables where rownum <= 50;'
  cmd
from all_tab_cols where table_name =
-- MODIFY USER_TABLES TO YOUR TABLE HERE [3]:
'USER_TABLES'
)
union all
(select 'exit
 EOF' from dual);
```

You can test this query and then replace USER_TABLES with Your own table name at three places (following the [1],[2],[3] line).

After that take the SQL*Plus result and when You run is You ought to get the expected result.

Hope it helps.